# Date Format Not Recognized

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting

I am trying to format cells containing a date based on a date in another cell.  The code seems to work but only if the "AM" or "PM" of the to be formatted cell matches the reference cell. So for instance, if the reference cell (AA11 in this example) has a date:time of 12/12/2019  8:00:00 AM, then only cells that are +0, +1, +2 etc. days and have the "AM" suffix will be formatted.  Cells that are +0, +1, +2 etc. days and have the "PM" suffix are not be formatted.  Is there any code that I need to add so that AM and PM are recognized?

```
`Sub ChangeColor()
myDate = Range("AA11").Value
Set MR = Range("$A2:$BU300")
For Each Cell In MR
    If (Cell.Value) = myDate Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    If (Cell.Value) = DateAdd("d", 1, myDate) Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    If (Cell.Value) = DateAdd("d", 2, myDate) Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 77
    If (Cell.Value) = DateAdd("d", 3, myDate) Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    If (Cell.Value) = DateAdd("d", 4, myDate) Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 32
    If (Cell.Value) = DateAdd("d", 5, myDate) Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
    If (Cell.Value) = DateAdd("d", 6, myDate) Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 31
    If (Cell.Value) = DateAdd("d", 7, myDate) Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Next
       Range("W4").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-300
End Sub`
```

Comment: Can you add a sample table of your data that you're working with? Also verify your cell is formatted properly

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.  I can say that it is a whole spreadsheet with various dates in the format mentioned above.  I am trying to highlight dates that are +0, +1, +2, +3 days etc. from a reference date. I hope this will help you help me.

Comment: Dates are tricky, especially when dealing with equalities and time.  Rememeber that date/time are stored as doubles with the time as the decimal part of the day.  So even if the the date/times look the same down to the second by the format they may not have the same decimal when going out to 15 sig digits.  Also remember that 6:00:00 AM is not the same as 6:00:00 PM.  the first is stored as `0.25` and the second `0.75` in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on date/times.  Can you suggest anyway that I can ensure that the "AM"/"PM" is recognized so it can be properly formatted

Comment: do you want the exact time to matter or only the date?  Are you saying the 6:00:00 AM should equal 6:00:00 PM?  I do not know what you are really trying to do here.  If you want the time to matter than you will need to round to the nearest second,minute,hour(Which ever you want).  If you want just the date to matter use `INT()` to strip the time from the date.

Comment: Let's try some debugging here. Try changing `myDate` to `Cell.Value` in your DateAdd() method. If it changes the colors for everything on the sheet then its an issue related to what @ScottCraner has suggested. Also change the format on the cell to a decimal format so you can physically see the numerics. After doing this inspect one that is supposed to change and identify which numeric is not equivalent.

Comment: Your question needs clarification.  If by **days difference** you mean **calendar days**, then compare the `Int` value of `myDate` to the `Int` value of `Cell.Value`.  If you mean **24 hours**, then compare the hours difference and divide by 24.

Comment: **Suggestion**: i would use `Case` statement for this rather than multiple `IF` statements